# Need clarification about constant expressions

Tags: c, constant-expression

K&R c 2nd edition(section 2.3) mentions

> A constant expression is an expression that involves only constants. Such expressions may be evaluated at during compilation rather than run-time, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant can occur

however, I have several doubts regarding it:

1. Will this expression be considered as constant expression?

   ```
   const int x=5;
   const int y=6;
   int z=x+y;
   ```

   i.e using `const` keyword is considered constant expression or not?
2. Is there any technique by which we can check whether an expression was evaluated during compilation or during run-time?
3. Are there any cases where compile time evaluation produces different result than run-time evaluation?
4. Should I even care about it? (maybe I use it to optimize my programs)

Comment: Read the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6); K&R is not the standard and quite outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Perhaps. A compiler can *add* more forms of constant expressions, so if it can prove to itself that the variable references are constant enough it can compute the expression at compile-time.
2. You can (of course) disassemble the code and see what the compiler did.
3. Not if the compiler is standards-compliant, no. The standard says "The semantic rules for the evaluation of a constant expression are the same as for nonconstant expressions" (§6.6 11 in the C11 draft).
4. Not very much, no. :) But do use `const` for code like that anyway!

Comment: Sir, May I ask about answer 3? `NULL`-dereference will produce different result, if I'm not wrong. Please enlight.

Comment: @SouravGhosh You can't dereference pointers in a constant expression, as far as I know? You can use pointers (including `NULL`) with `sizeof`, but you can't do a standalone dereferencing.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that only, right. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> *using const keyword is considered constant expression or not?*

**>>** No, it is not a constant. The variable using `const` is called *`const` qualified*, but not a compile time constant.

> *Is there any technique by which we can check whether an expression was evaluated during compilation or during run-time?*

**>>** (*as mentioned in Mr. [Unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind)'s answer*) Disassemble the code.

> *Are there any cases where compile time evaluation produces different result than run-time evaluation?*

**>>** No, it will not. refer to Chapter `§6.6 11`, `C11` standard.

<sup>FWIW, in case of usage with `sizeof` operator (compile time, though not constant expression), NULL pointer dereference will be ok. Compile time NULL pointer dereference invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).</sup>

> *Should I even care about it? (maybe I use it to optimize my programs)*

**>>** Opinion-based, so won't answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. x and y are const, z is not. compiller probably will substitute x and y , but will not substitute z. but probably compiller will calc 5 + 6 as well and will assign to z directly.
2. not sure you can check generated assembler code, but I do not know how this can be done.
3. not. compile time means expression is already calculated in run time.
4. I care :) but it appies only when you need fast execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. In C, the `const` *qualifier* is just a guarantee given by the programmer to the compiler that he will not change the object. Otherwise it does not have special meanings as in C++. The *initializer* for such objects with file- or global scope has to be a [*constant expression*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6).
2. As an extension, gcc has a [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) function (`int __builtin_constant_p (exp)`) to determine if a value is constant.
3. No, it shall not - unless you exploit *implementation defined* or *undefined behaviour* and compiler and target behave differently. [1]
4. As *constant expressions* are evaluated at compile-time, they safe processing time and often code space and possibly data space. Also, in some places (e.g. global initializers), only *constant expressions* are allowed. See the standard.

---

[1]: One example is right shifting a signed negative integer constant, e.g. `-1 >> 24`. As that is implementation defined, the compiler might yield a different result from a program run using a variable which holds the same value:

```
int i = -1;
(-1 >> 24) == (i >> 24)
^             ^--- run-time evaluated by target
+--- compile-time evaluated by compiler
```

The comparison might fail.